# How to convert nested list of numbers to list of strings?

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of lists below

```
p=[[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,1]]
```

How do I put the sublist into a string?

For example, desire result is:

```
p=["1234","2341"]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It can be done by converting every integer to string and joining the strings:

```
p = [''.join(map(str, sub_list)) for sub_list in p]  # ['1234', '2341']
```

Ever every nested list, like `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, `map(str, [1, 2, 3, 4])` would create a list of strings. In this example: `['1', '2', '3', '4']`. Using the [join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) function, the string-numbers are mapped into a single string, `'1234'`.

Since this operation is performed for every sub-list, the result is a a list of the joined strings.